# How to calculate alpha reliability of a scale (factor) when it is expressed in factor scores?

Tags: factor-analysis, reliability, cronbachs-alpha, scale-construction

I am doing a Principal Axis Factor Analysis, I found two factors and saved the factor scores for each, using the regression approach (as in the SPSS option by default).

My question is, how do I calculate the reliability of each of my two factor scores variables now?

In other studies, I already used factor analysis and computed "factor scores" (scale scores) manually by simply adding or averaging the ratings on the original items. As I manually computed factor scores, I chose the items to calculate for each factor score (I chose those with the best factor loadings on each factor). Then I also calculated the **Cronbach's alpha** on these same items (which sum is my factor score).

And now I'm in doubt: because this time I have factor scores as automatically computed/saved by a factor analysis program. I guess all the items have contributed in some way to compute the factor scores, but I don't know how, and likely that they gave unequal contributions. So, how do I know which of the items I should calculate the Cronbach's alpha on?

Comment: A factor (whose values are estimated, say, as factor scores) is not a _collection of items_ but is a latent trait (single latent "item") which loads the manifest items. Since it is single, not collection, it can't have homogeneity-sort of reliability ("internal consistency" measured by alpha). When you check for alpha-homogeneity you input a collection of original items constituting and measuring one scale. Now, factor scores is the single, constructed "item" measuring the scale.

Comment: (cont.) With original items, you may ask how much duplicates of each other are they; with factor, they are already assembled in an optimal formula (of the score)and are not seen as distinct items anymore.

Comment: (cont.) In other words, the decision to compute/save (regression) factor scores indicates that you are satisfied with the factor model and the set of items used in the analysis. The decision logically precludes further manipulation with items to increase homogeneity. If you don't like the homogeneity, check alpha, remove/add items so to improve it, then do final factoring and save factor scores (if you will need factor scores in your future activities)

Comment: The stem of your difficulty is theoretical/logical: factor (scores) is a construct, a criterion - a category belonging to the discourse of validity. Alpha homogeneity is belongs to the discourse of reliability. In reliability analysis, we deal not with "target trait" vs systematic bias, but with "true score" vs random noise.

Comment: Thx so much for your comments. So, just to resume, I am suppose to calculate factor scores after having optimized (removed unadequate items) the composition of the factor. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes. Factor score is the (approximate) value of the latent factor. Therefore to trust it you must believe that your factor is "what and how" you like it, that it loads relevant items. You may select items for factoring based both on previous factoring or on reliability analysis - your right. Note that factor itself does not require that items it loads correlate really tightly (are homogeneous). The homogeneity/reliability is _yours_ psychometric demand, not f. analysis'.